# Flux subscribe method: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Flux

Tags: spring-webflux

The response form webclient is a flux which i expect to return in my endpoint.
the `doSomething()` method contains business logic.

I am trying to implement backpressure using subscribe(), i am unable to capture the response as a flux. It returns a `Disposable` instead of a flux, and hence the ClassCastException :

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Flux
```

```
return (Flux<Book>) webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/getBooks/bn2")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Book.class)
                .log()
                .subscribe(
                    System.out::println,
                    err -> err.printStackTrace(),
                    () -> System.out.println("All 16 items have been successfully processed!!!"),
                    subscription -> {
                            doSomething();
                            subscription.request(2);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

What is the alternate approach?

Comment: This user has never accepted an answer.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Let me clarify, at the time of the above comment, this user had never accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about which `Flux::subscribe` you are invoking.

You are invoking [public final Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-).

If you want to invoke [subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> actual)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-org.reactivestreams.Subscriber-)  then you need to provide an anonymous inner class like `new Subscribe() {...}`. You cannot use a lambda to do that since the interface has 4 methods.

Comment: true.. essentially i'm trying to publish from the subscriber again..